# How to create a text child without tag using GDataXml

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

How to create the following Html using GDataXml:

`<p> First string child <a>link</a> second string child</p>`

Note that `<p>` has three child:

1. Text without any tag: `"First string child"`
2. Link: `<a>link</a>`
3. Text without any tag: `second string child.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can creat a text without tag by using method:

> - (id)textWithStringValue:(NSString *)value

as the following:

```
GDataXMLElement * pElement = [GDataXMLElement elementWithName:@"p"];
    [pElement addChild:[GDataXMLNode textWithStringValue:@" First string child "]];
    [pElement addChild:[GDataXMLNode elementWithName:@"a" stringValue:@"link"]];
    [pElement addChild:[GDataXMLNode textWithStringValue:@" second string child"]];
```